# Independence of measurable maps

Tags: measure-theory

I'm a bit confused about the concept of independence of measurable maps. I've found the following definition in Pollard's "A user's guide to measure theoretic probability":

Measurable maps $X_{i}$, for $i \in I$ from $\Omega$ into measurable spaces $(\mathcal{X}_{i}, \mathcal{A}_{i})$ are said to be independent if the sigma-fields they generate are independent, that is if

$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i \in S}\{X_{i} \in A_{i}\}\right) = \Pi_{i\in S}\mathbb{P}\{X_{i} \in A_{i}\}$ for all finite subsets $S$ of the index set $I$ and all choices of $A_{i} \in \mathcal{A}_{i}$ for $i \in S$.

Wouldn't one have to start with a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ (where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes a measure, not necessarily a probability measure) and define independence of measurable maps (with domain $\Omega$) *with respect to*  measure $\mathbb{P}$?

It seems to me that this is implicit in the above definition, since the measure $\mathbb{P}$ is used. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - This depends on the underlying measure. To see this, just notice that if $m$ is a Dirac measure (which means there is a point $x$ such that for every event $E$, $m(E) = 1$ iff $x \in E$) then for any two events $E, F$, $m(E \cap F) = m(E)m(F)$. Hence every pair of sigma subalgebras are independent w.r.t. Dirac measure. With a little effort, I am sure you can construct more interesting counterexamples.